# Can't create a function in bash without getting a command not found error

Tags: bash, sed, echo

I'm writing a bash script to edit a youtube video name and I wrote a sed function for it:

```
function longSed(){
         ins0=$1
         ins1=$( $ins0 | sed 's/and//g;s/ or//g;s/the//g;s/And//g;s/yet//g;s/the//g;s/so//g;s/ a//g;s/ A//g' )
         return $ins1
}

v2=longSed v1
echo "$v1 --> $v2"
```

But I keep receiving a `command not found` error on the second-to-last line no matter what I do. What am I missing here?

**EDIT** : This is the entire script:

```
#!/bin/bash

v0=$(youtube-dl --skip-download --get-title --no-warnings $1 | sed 2d )
v1=$(youtube-dl --skip-download --get-title --no-warnings $1 | sed 2d | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r ' | head -c 64 )

function longSed(){
         ins0=$1
         ins1=$( $ins0 | sed 's/and//g;s/ or//g;s/the//g;s/And//g;s/yet//g;s/the//g;s/so//g;s/ a//g;s/ A//g' )
         return $ins1
}

v2=$(longSed v1)
echo "$v0 --> $v2"
```

I probably shouldn't be using `sed` for an entire wordlist like that, but I don't want a separate wordlist file.

Comment: try `v2=$(longSed v1)`... see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution for details on assigning command output to variable

Comment: Now it's saying that there's an error on line 8: `./NameStrip04.sh: line 8: v1: command not found` and that `ins1=$( $ins0 | sed 's/and//g;s/ or//g;s/the//g;s/And//g;s/yet//g;s/the//g;s/so//g;s/ a//g;s/ A//g' )` is a problem.

Comment: `$ins0 | sed ...` means you want to execute contents of `ins0` as a command.. you are passing `v1` as parameter.. hence the error if `v1` is not a valid command.. you probably wanted `ins1=$( echo "$ins0" | sed ...)` ??

Comment: I haven't fully tried to understand the script you wrote.. see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info for common issues.. for ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash ...

Comment: Run your script through shellcheck.net

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: Not causing your problem, but the syntax for a `bash` function is either `function longSed {` or `longSed() {`(POSIX).

Comment: `function longSed ()` is fine, though redundant.